# Как объединить VPN Server + Socks Proxy?

Tags: proxy, vpn, openvpn

Суть вопроса, поднял на Debian OpenVPN сервер и есть у меня прокси германского сервера, можно ли как то реализовать трафик по схеме Client -> OpenVPN -> SOCKS -> Internet?

Comment: Ответ на [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/712998/how-to-use-openvpn-behind-a-http-and-https-proxy)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/671112

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно, подключайся к прокси через VPN.

VPN работает на канальном/сетевом уровне, а SOCKS-прокси на транспортном. То при обsчном подключении к socks с локальной машины трафик будут проходить сначала через VPN, а потом из сети VPN на SOCKS-прокси.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59829/discussion-on-answer-by-alex78191---vpn-server-socks-proxy).