# Использование SOCKS без прямого подключения

Tags: proxy, vpn, openvpn

Вопрос, как реализовать схему : на стороне клиента я просто подключаюсь к VPN серверу, а VPN сервер уже отправлял трафик на прокси... т.е. без настроек на устройствах клиента, клиент -> впн сервер -> сокс прокси

Answer (score -1):

Нужно перенаправлять пакеты на порт приложения, которое будет посылать пакеты по протоколу SOCKS, рекомендую RedSocks.

Пример настройки Linux https://habrahabr.ru/post/116360/

Answer (score -1):

Готовые варианты мне не известны, но при желании можно написать свой vpn-сервер.

В отличии от обычных vpn-серверов, не понадобится даже создавать сетевой интерфейс. С другой стороны, понадобится своя реализация протокола TCP.